# The maximum cardinality of an $\epsilon$-separated subset of functions.

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the space, $X$, of functions $\{1, 2, \ldots, d\}\rightarrow [0,1]$ where $d$ is some integer, equipped with a metric $m(f,g):=\frac{1}{d}\sum\limits_{i=1}^d|f(i)-g(i)|$. I am interested in finding, approximately, the cardinality, let us denote it by $N_\epsilon$, of a maximal $\epsilon$-separated subset of $X$. (Recall that a subset of a metric space is $\epsilon$-separated if each pair of distinct members are at least a distance $\epsilon$ apart). I should remark that I am interested in an upper bound, and I expect this upper bound to be very rough.

One of my approaches has been to give a lower bound on the volume of $\epsilon/2$ ball's in $X$ (where volume is the standard $d$-dimensional euclidean measure). Then the reciprocal of that will give an upper bound on $N_\epsilon$. To estimate the volume of a $B(f, \epsilon/2)$ ball I have used that the $g$'s which satisfy $|f(i)-g(i)|<\epsilon/2$ for all $i$, belong to it. Provided that $\epsilon/2 \leq f \leq 1-\epsilon/2$ the volume of such $g$'s is $\epsilon^d$ so $\text{vol}(B(f, \epsilon/2)\geq \epsilon^d$. This gives roughly an upper bound on $N_\epsilon$ by $(1/\epsilon)^d$. But I realize that this is quite useless as this is already close to the cardinality of a maximum $\epsilon$-separated subset of $X$, when $X$ is equipped with the supremum metric and we would expect $N_\epsilon$ to be much, much less. Any tips on how I can improve the upper bound or references to some literature that deals with these type of combinatorial questions would be much appreciated.